# Combine video and audio and make the final duration the same as first input with FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have two files - `video.mp4` and `audio.mp3`, and I want to combine them. The final video must have duration of the `video.mp4`.

I don't know which of these two files is longer so I cannot use the `-shortest` option.

This is what I have so far:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy final.mp4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -af apad -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest final.mp4
```

The `apad` adds indefinite silence to the audio, so the video will always be the shortest stream.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found is to have a function which first returns the duration of the first file. This is of course bash script, which you can copy/paste into shell, or write a .sh bash script.

```
function getDuration() {
  ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mp4
}
```

and then use that function to return the duration, and use that with the `-t` parameter

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -t $(getDuration) -c copy final.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you! +1. But I accept @Mulvya 's answer because of his one-line solution.